# Is it possible for wix to add entries to IIS's ISAPI and CGI Restrictions?

Tags: wix, wix-iisextension

I'm writing a wix installer for a website, which includes ISAPI filters that need to be added into IIS manager's ISAPI and CGI Restrictions entries. Is this possible in wix? Must I use a custom action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I should be able to do this using [`<iis:WebServiceExtension>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/webserviceextension.html) Even though that page says "The WebServiceExtension property is used by the Web server to **determine** whether a Web service extension is permitted to run", that might not be accurate since it will also be used to create a new entry.